# Why does my UITableView keep resizing?

Tags: uitableview

I made a UINavigationController that pushes a `UITabBarController into view through Storyboards.`  I have a total of 5 tabs on the UITabBarController all of which are UITableviewControllers and want only one of the 5 tabs to show the Navigation Bar.

The other 4 tabs (when selected) hides the navigation bar with `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`...

Everything works fine besides the fact that every time i switch back to the first tab, my header view grows about about 20pts taller each time. I am using `Xcode 5 and iOS7.`  Everything is pretty much made in `storyboards` so I don't know what other code you might need.  Please Help

Comment: provide some code or images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with:

```
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

in the viewWillAppear: